# Requesting data from OpenLayers to standalone GeoWebCache

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geowebcache, standalone

I'm using OpenLayers and GeoServer to make a GIS application. For the moment, GeoWebCache is directly integrated into GeoServer, but for my future needs, I'll need to have it as a standalone.
I've dowloaded it and deployed it, but now I can't make it work.

For the moment, I want to use it as a "firewall".
Typically, in OpenLayers I have such requests :

```
"http://129.182.247.82:8080/geoserver/wms,"
```

to retrieve WMS data.

What I want to do, is to change this URL to make it point to the GeoWebCache stand-alone, and then the GeoWebCache stand-alone will call the right layers into GeoServer.

I followed this documentation : http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/quickstart/index.html

But I can't make it work. I had no geowebcache.xml to test layer so I created one from github and put it into WEB-INF/classes, but it still does not work.
Inside my geowebcache-core-context.xml I've added lines like this :

```
<bean id="gwcWMSConfig" class="org.geowebcache.config.GetCapabilitiesConfiguration">
...
<constructor-arg value="http://http://129.182.247.82:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&amp;request=GetCapabilities&amp;version=1.1.0">
```

and this

```
<bean id="gwcTLDispatcher" class="org.geowebcache.layer.TileLayerDispatcher">
....
<constructor-arg ref="gwcGridSetBroker"/>
<constructor-arg ref="gwcWMSConfig"/>
<constructor-arg ref="gwcXmlConfig"/>
</bean>
```

But still nothing is working, and I'm quite lost.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation states that the `geowebcache-core-context.xml` should be stored in the `WEB-INF` folder. In other words, not the `classes` subfolder. Move the file up into the `WEB-INF` folder and restart GeoWebCache.

Comment: Hmhmh Ok I'll test it. Because in the documentation, it is written "This information is set in the geowebcache.xml file, which is typically available at opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/geowebcache/WEB-INF/classes" Edit : I tested, not working. I get tge geowebcache file there https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/data/citecsw-2.0.2/gwc/geowebcache.xml and I've decommented.

Comment: I think you are getting confused between geowebcache.xml and geowebcache-core-context.xml. The geowebcache.xml file contains the details GeoWebCache needs to give you the layer options. And geowebcache-core-context.xml allows you to specify the location of a WMS GetCapabilities document so that GeoWebCache can automatically configure layers for you from your WMS.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. Still, the core-context is in the WEB-INF folder and the geowebcache.xml inside Web-INF/classes. I guess I have to edit the geowebcache.xml file to make it work. But since I did not had it when I installed...